# Gmail ignoring height in empty <td> cell (HTML Email)

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

I've just started using a new HTML email software (was using Campaign Monitor but now having to use a plugin within our CMS).
Our template uses some empty  cells at the top with different background colors for aesthetic purposes.
When using Campaign Monitor these showed fine in Gmail but in the new software (eCampaign) Gmail is totally ignoring the height of the cells, making them all 1 pixel high.
I tried adding height="x" and style="height: x;" but neither seem to work. 
I want to avoid using spacer gifs if I can.
Further down the email I've put in a 
 tag but this makes the height too large then.
I've seen some suggestions of wrapping the 
 in a tag but not sure if that will work.
Any suggestions?? Need an answer asap!

My code is as follows:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="6" colspan="2" bgcolor="#edede9" style="font-size:1px; line-height:6; height:6;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="6" colspan="2" bgcolor="#c4c3b6"><!-- --></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="1" colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff"><!-- --></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use a trans_dot.gif or other spacer image within the empty cells. It cant be done in any otherway.

So find or make a 1px * 1px transparent image and insert.
If a cell is without text or images it will collapse in 9 out of 10 email clients